# copy uv from one object to another but projected

Tags: uv

i want to add a uv map to an object (plane01) at the same exact position of another object (plane02).
Can anyone help me solve this puzzle?
[image: objects]

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify it a little bit more, ideally show the before and after, using some image texture that is very readable in regards to coordinate (a color grid)

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks. Can you see the image i attached to my post? Not sure if i did it the right way.

Comment: I agree, it's not easy to understand, do you mean that the image of plane 2 should be the center of the image of plane 1? In that case put the 2 planes at the same location, keep them selected and unwrap? Or please elaborate?

Comment: Select the 3 objects, switch to Edit mode and unwrap them together?

Answer (score 1):

For using the small plane to adjust the texture of the big plane you can try this:
[image]
Notice that this do not transfer UVs from one object to another, is just a texture placement aid.

Comment: Hi and thanks alot for help and sorry for not beeing precise. Basically yes there is no need to transfer uv but to position scale rotate additional uvs. I added another picture to the original post. It is like putting small stickers to a langer object. but i want to delete the original stickers after adjusting the uvs so getting position from the object `sticker`is not lasting.

Comment: I´m an aware that i need to combine these images in the shader tree with mix shader but that is a good way. At the end don´t want one texture map with the original and the a b c in it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Geometry Nodes you can fake a UV transfer by transforming the UVMap of the object based on the transformation of an external object. Here the helper planes are with viewport visibility set to wireframe.

You are not merging UVs, just generating one new Attribute per decal to be used as mapping vector.

This is a somehow limited inital approach that works with parallel planes with proportional scale, assuming their vertices are fit into the UVMap (as in a new plane by default). Just an idea to play with.

Once satisfied with the result, attributes are preserved after applying geometry nodes modifiers and helper objects can be deleted.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Luis, thanks again for putting your time in my tasks :) I think that´s a really suitable starting point, i will play around with that and i´m sure this will help alot!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want, if you want the small planes to perfectly overlay the large one, you could select them all, choose the top view, switch to *Edit* mode and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project from View*:

[image]

Give them the exact same material, result:

[image]

Comment: Hi moonboots, thanks for your answer and sorry for delay. Your solution is nice but not what i had in mind. It is more the other way round so that the texture of the big plane is combined with the textures (which are different) of the small planes. so it is not just one image texture applied to several objects. But thanks anyway for your Effort.